# Is there any configuration to add jsonplugin to apama project

Tags: java, events, iot, apama

I have created an apama project using softwareAG designer. And tried to access JSONPlugin as below. My question is can we use this plugin directly in my monitor or is there any extra configuration to make it available in my monitor. Now I am receiving an error like `the name JSON in the com.apama namespace does not exist (error reported to the client)`

Can someone suggest me how to do this?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could figure out the issue. Below is the solution

Add epl bundle from configure apama build path.

epl bundle name : JSON support : \JSONPlugin.bnd